# Display data only once

Tags: php, mysql

I have created a contactlist for parents in a daycare center. Now I wish to display it on the webpage. So far, it technically works perfect but it's the layout that I'm not happy with.

Short on how my database works:
Each parent can have one or more children and each child can have one or more parents - a many to many relationship. I have broken it down to three tables - parents, children and parent_children in order to make a one to many relationship. Then I have used JOIN and everything displays nicely. However, since it show every entity it gets rather cluttered to display it on an webpage. I'll explain with an example:

Family 1: Mark and Alice Wilson have two children, John and Bill.
Family 2: Peter and Jessica Robertson have one child, Lisa.

```
Current layout:
Parent                Child
-------------------------------
Mark Wilson           John Wilson
Mark Wilson           Bill Wilson
Alice Wilson          John Wilson
Alice Wilson          Bill Wilson

Peter Robertson       Lisa Robertson
Jessica Robertson     Lisa Robertson
-------------------------------

Desired layout:
Parent                Child
-------------------------------
Mark Wilson           John Wilson
Alice Wilson          Bill Wilson

Peter Robertson       Lisa Robertson
Jessica Robertson
-------------------------------
```

Is there any good way to get the desired layout?

---

Ok, so now I've come so far as to get this working in ONE column, depending on how I use GROUP_CONCAT:

Code:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(parents.name) AS Parents, children.name
FROM parents p
LEFT JOIN parents_children pc USING(id_parent)
LEFT JOIN children c USING(id_child)
GROUP BY pc.id_parent;
```

Result:

```
Parents                             Children
-----------------------------------------------
Mark Wilson, Alice Wilson           Bill Wilson
Mark Wilson, Alice Wilson           John Wilson
Peter Robertson, Jessica Robertson  Lisa Robertson
```

Likewise, if I GROUP_CONCAT children.name and GROUP BY pc.id_child instead I get:

```
Parents                Children
------------------------------------------
Mark Wilson            Bill Wilson, John Wilson
Alice Wilson           Bill Wilson, John Wilson
Peter Robertson        Lisa Robertson
Jessica Robertson      Lisa Robertson
```

I really want a combo of these, with the following result:

```
Parents                                Children
----------------------------------------------------
Mark Wilson, Alice Wilson              Bill Wilson, John Wilson
Peter Robertson, Jessica Robertson     Lisa Robertson
```

Comment: Have you tried DISTINCT on child id?

Comment: Interesting question. This is one case where I probably wouldn't have normalised the data to that extent, and just had two fields in the child table that refer back to the parent table. As an aside, how would your sample data cope if Peter Robertson had a child with Alice Wilson? Would everyone need to be treated as one big family?

Comment: I suspect the result you are looking for may be achieved using the SQL `DISTINCT` clause, plus a little database jedi magic. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/distinct-optimization.html

Comment: "Family" as an entity doesn't exist in the database. Each parent is it's own "entity" and to that, one or more children are connected. So if any couple seperates, nothing changes. They both still have the same children.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    Parents
  , GROUP_CONCAT(name ORDER BY name) AS Children
FROM
  ( SELECT 
        GROUP_CONCAT(p.id_parent ORDER BY p.name) AS parents_ids
      , GROUP_CONCAT(p.name ORDER BY p.name) AS Parents
      , pc.id_child
      , c.name
    FROM parents p 
      JOIN parents_children pc USING(id_parent)
      JOIN children c USING(id_child)
    GROUP BY pc.id_child
  ) AS tmp 
GROUP BY parents_ids ;
```

You can test it in: [SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/795d5/1)

Answer (score 2):

SELECT DISTINCT should limit them down to one instance of each entity in the parent table.

Comment: Tried it but the result was still the same.

Answer (score 1):

Table parents:

```
CREATE TABLE `parents` (
```

`id_part` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `parent` varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_part`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

Table child:

```
CREATE TABLE `child` (
```

`id_child` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `child` varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL,
  `f_name` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `m_name` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_child`),
  KEY `m_key` (`m_name`),
  KEY `f_key` (`f_name`),
  CONSTRAINT `f_key` FOREIGN KEY (`f_name`) REFERENCES `parents` (`id_part`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `m_key` FOREIGN KEY (`m_name`) REFERENCES `parents` (`id_part`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

Query to join two tables

```
SELECT DISTINCT
```

GROUP_concat(child.child),
p1.parent,
p2.parent
FROM
child
Inner Join parents AS p1 ON p1.id_part = child.f_name
Inner Join parents AS p2 ON p2.id_part = child.m_name
GROUP BY 
p1.parent,
p2.parent

Result

### Children's name | father's name | mother's name

### x,y,z           | father 1      | mother 1

### q,r             | father 2      | mother 2

### t,j             | father 3      | mother 3

Comment: Sorry, but I use three tables, since it'a a many-to-many relationship. The main problem I found out is that the table connecting parents and children (parents_child) doesn't have anything to concatenate.

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions for this issue:

1. On php side iterate through the array and create an array where key of 
   `[$parent_1 . '|' . $parent2]` contains another array with children.
2. On SQL end of thing do something similar to this:

   ```
   SELECT 
       GROUP_CONCAT(Parents.name ORDER BY Parents.parents_id, '|') AS parents, 
       Children.name as child
   FROM Children 
       LEFT JOIN CildrentParents USING( children_id )
       LEFT JOIN Parents USING( parent_id )
   GROUP BY Childrent.children_id
   ```

   and then work with this dataset.

P.S. i don't see, how just adding `DISTINCT` to the original query, would solve this ... maybe i am missing something here.

### Update

And what exactly is stopping you from using PHP to create an array, where each `parent` key contains a list of children?

Comment: I manage to get everything on one single row when using your syntax.

Comment: @Sandokan , was this what you needed, or was it not ? I cannot understand from that sentence.

Comment: Sorry. What I meant was that I only get 1 row presented and ALL entities are shown on it. However, I realized that I had forgotten the last GROUP BY clause. Still, it doesn't exactly work the way I like, although now I'm one step closer.